# How to add a parent to every child in a json array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I'm working on a Web Service in ASP.NET that has two methods, what I want to do is to return the data in JSON format, I'm usin JSON.NET library.

This is one of the methods:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetReservas()
    {
        var json = "";

        var data = from result in DCHotel.visHTLReservaciones select result;

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        return json;          
    }
```

When I run the web service, this is the output in my browser:

> [{"id":1,"name":"jose","age":22},{"id":2,"name":"john","age":21}]

And what I need is something like this:

> ["person":[{"id":1,"name":"jose","age":22}],"person":[{"id":2,"name":"john","age":21}]]

I need to add parents to every child in the array, I don't know how to do it, and I searched a lot and can't find the solution to this, hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: The JSON you say you want is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy, change your linq query to this:

```
var data = from result in DCHotel.visHTLReservaciones select new { person =  result };
```

Instead of taking just the result you encapsulate it on an anonymous class.

Cheers.